# Java game loop delta not working

Tags: java, game-loop

Hello I have game loop where I can change framerate. But when I change framerate to other, delta time not working fine. For example when framerate is lower everything is faster.

Here is game loop:

```
double delta = 0.0;
private double framerate = 60.0;
private double frameTime = 1.0/framerate;

public void run() {
    runFlag = true;
    int frames = 0;
    double frameCounter = 0;

    double lastTime = (double)System.nanoTime()/(double)1000000000L;
    double unprocessedTime = 0;

    while(runFlag) {
        boolean render = false;

        double startTime = (double)System.nanoTime()/(double)1000000000L;
        double passedTime = startTime - lastTime;
        lastTime = startTime;

        unprocessedTime += passedTime;
        frameCounter += passedTime;

        while(unprocessedTime > frameTime) {
            render = true;

            unprocessedTime -= frameTime;

            tick();

            delta = frameTime;

            if(frameCounter >= 1.0) {
                this.frames = frames;
                Display.setTitle("  FPS: "+frames+"  DELTA: "+(float)delta);

                frames = 0;
                frameCounter = 0;
            }
        }
        if(render) {
            render();

            frames++;
        } else {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        Display.update();
    }
    destroy();
}
```

What is wrong with this game loop ?

Comment: where do you declare delta variable ?

Comment: double delta is over the constuctor so I don't write it.

Answer (score 1):

Your delta will be **always** equal to 1/60, but that's not what delta time is. Delta is the time that passed between current and previous call. Here's an example:

```
double delta;
double currentTime, lastTime;

while (doingStuff)
{
    currentTime = getCurrentTime() //You have to define this method somewhere

    delta = currentTime - lastTime;

    lastTime = currentTime;
}
```

In this example, delta is the difference between time of last and current iteration of the loop.

The "delta" you calculated is the perfect time you want between frames. And there's a **giant** difference between the time you want, and the time you actually have.

Comment: where i can put render ?

Comment: I see you just copy code. I don't encourage that. You should be able to figure it out yourself. Only thing you have to change is the delta time calculation. It's not that hard.